# How do I best share a shared account's private key?

Tags: key-management, oauth, websites

I made a website which among other things allows users to sign up to events. The HTML form is filled out and submitted, which automatically updates a google spreadsheet with all applications. This of course uses IDs and auth keys, which I can't just throw on the internet (these are hardcoded strings in seperate files in the backend of my website).
The problem is that I am not the only one who should have access to the source code (I built the website, but a few others should be able to make small adjustments). They can easily clone the git repository (private with a few accounts whitelisted), but if they want the keys I need to push them online onto github, which I don't want to do.

How do I securely share this info? Can I just push it to Github, or should I get some other kind of file sharing system to do it?
More generally, is it even safe to handle keys in this way?

Comment: Welcome to the community. What about a smartcard or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, a clarification: "private key" is generally the counterpart to a "public key", and should **NEVER** be shared. There's no reason to ever share a private key; anywhere you think you should share a private key, what you should actually do is have the other person generate a new public/private key pair, and give the public key (not the private key!) to you, and you put that public key wherever it's needed (e.g. in the `authorized_keys` file of a SSH configuration on a server, or in a GPG keyring, or as an allowed client certificate - certificates are a holder for public keys that provide some additional metadata - on a TLS server, or as a verification key for an asymmetrically-signed JWT. Thus, you can each use your own key pair), without the private key portions ever going outside of their owner's direct control.

However, it sounds like you're talking about a *secret* key, with no other part. A secret key might be an API key, or an OAuth client_secret, or an HMAC key such as for a JWT, or a symmetric encryption key... many possibilities.

---

As for your actual question, this is what deployment automation software - generally referred to as "CI/CD" ("Continuous Integration / Continuous Deployment", or sometimes "Delivery" instead of "Deployment") - is for. Github offers this feature, though I've never used it; there are also various commercial and open-source solutions you can deploy yourself. In all cases, the basic functioning is the same: you configure the CI/CD with the information necessary for a deployment (where to upload the build artifacts, what credentials to use, what commands to execute/environment variables to set/etc.), plus telling it how to perform a build (what repos to build from, what build flags to use, etc.) and when to perform a build (typically upon merge to a particular branch or branches of one or more repos, but possibly with other conditions such as passing a static analysis scan), and finally when to perform a deployment (typically upon successful build of a given repo, though again sometimes with additional conditions).

The cool thing about this is, you can separate the permissions for each aspect of this system. For example, you can allow other people to contribute to one of your repositories, without allowing them to see or modify the CI/CD configuration. Or you can allow them to trigger deploys only to a pre-production staging environment, from which only you can promote a build to production (typically after some testing). You can also use the "continuous integration" part to do things like ensuring that a pull request builds successfully and passes various checks (security scans, linting, etc.) before somebody is allowed to open a pull request or merge code to the main branch.

Comment: It is a secret key, not a private key, I believe. Thanks for the suggestions, I'll look into Github's possibilities once I have some time.

Comment: I checked this out a bit and I believe this isn't what I am looking for. We are using a private repository, if you have access to it you should also be allowed to see the secrets. CI/CD is useful for things like big projects with some kind of hierarchy or an open source program with some private aspects, which isn't applicable to my situation.
Can I just upload the secrets to the private git repo? Or is this considered unsafe?

Comment: Git's history means that even after you change a secret in the repo, its old value will still be visible to anybody with access. Since people reuse secrets a lot (don't do that!) and don't always rotate them all at the same time, that's bad. It also means that if you want to, in the future, add somebody who can read the repo (even if not contribute), they'll be able to read the secrets out of it unless you rotate them and place the new values somewhere else, instead of updating the ones in the repo. I don't recommend either approach. If CI/CD is too much, create a second repo for the secrets.